# store and retrieve linked list via files using c++

Tags: c++, file, linked-list, store

I have created a program to store and retrieve linked list using c++, but unfortunately my program does not retrieve data properly and returns code 0xC0000005. What is wrong with my program? I am a beginner.

```
//C++ code
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

struct link
{
    link(int dat, link *nxt): data(dat), another(nxt)
    {
    }
    int data;
    link *another;
};

struct list
{
    link *first;
    ~list();
    list();
    void addnew();
    void displl();
}list;

list::list()
{
    fstream datafile;
    datafile.open("datafile", ios::in | ios::app);
    datafile.seekg(0, ios::end);
    int eb = datafile.tellg();
    if(!eb)
    {
        first = NULL;
        return;
    }
    datafile.seekg(0, ios::beg);
    link *head, *current, *preceding;
    head = preceding = current = NULL;
    while(eb)
    {
        if(!current)
        {
            datafile.read((char *)&current, sizeof(link));
            current->another = NULL;
            head = current;
        }
        preceding = current;
        datafile.read((char *)&current->another, sizeof(link));
        current = current->another;
        current->another = NULL;
        preceding->another = current;
        eb--;
    }
    first = head;
}

void list::addnew()
{
    srand(time(0) + rand());
    first = new link(rand()%10, first);
}

void list::displl()
{
    link *current;
    cout << endl << " - ";
    for(current = first; current; current = current->another)
        cout << current->data << " - ";
    cout << endl;
}

list::~list()
{
    fstream datafile;
    datafile.open("datafile", ios::out | ios::app);
    link *temp;
    while(first != NULL)
    {
        temp = first;
        first = first->another;
        datafile.write((char *)&temp, sizeof(link));
        delete temp;
    }
    first = NULL;
}

int main()
{
    list.addnew();
    list.addnew();
    list.addnew();
    list.displl();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't compile with gcc. How do you compile it?

Comment: What line of code is crashing?

Answer (score 1):

My favorite advice for beginners is start small and simple, get it working perfectly, then add complexity a little at a time, testing at every step. You have three independent functions here: a basic list, assigning random values to a list, and reading/writing a list. You should have developed these independently, then combined them; the fact that you don't know which part is causing the trouble shows that you tried to write them all at once. (Well, the fact that their respective codes are entangled shows it too.)

The biggest problem is in the file-reading code (which is in the *default constructor* of all places). You are putting data into uninitialized memory:

```
link *current;
...
current = NULL;
...
datafile.read((char *)&current, sizeof(link));
```

That's like pouring hot coffee without first finding a cup. You should work out read/write -- and learn not to do this -- with simple types like `char` and `int` before you try it with complex types. Then try read/write with a single `link`. Then with a bunch of them.

Answer (score 0):

You get `0xC0000005` error because of **Illegal memory access** since you are doing pointer operations in your program. Because you are not providing full codes, you might be doing illegal operations like not initializing pointer in other part of your program.

Answer (score 0):

As Beta already indicated, the access violation occurs when attempting to read a link:

```
     ...
datafile.read((char *)&current, sizeof(link));
     ...
```

"current" is a pointer, and using the "&" operator on it gives a pointer to the memory occupied by the variable, itself (somewhere on the stack).  So the code attempts to read some link-sized chunk of garbage data into this pointer -- but this doesn't cause the access violation.  The exception occurs when "current" is dereferenced and used to write to a memeber of the "link" object that it points to:

```
current->another = NULL;
```

The value it loaded from datafile came from similarly incorrect serialization code  - no "link" data were ever saved.  All the file contains are old memory addresses from "link" objects allocated on the heap -- and these addresses are invalid because their memory was allocated in a previous program session.

Successfully serializing an object's byte image looks something like this:

```
datafile.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(temp), sizeof(*temp));
```

But the "link" object is not plain-old-data -- the pointer it contains will be invalid after you destroy this linked-to object.  So loading the list must include allocating memory for each link (like "addnew" does).

You probably just want to walk the list, starting at the head, and save the payload data from each link, like this:

```
datafile.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&temp->data), sizeof(temp->data));
```

Then, to load the list, for each node, read the payload into a temporary variable:

```
datafile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&temp_data), sizeof(temp_data));
```

If this operation succeeds, allocate and construct a heap "link" object and connect it to the previous node:

```
next_tail = new link(temp_data, 0);
tail->another = next_tail;
tail = next_tail;
```